# Android slider button widget

Tags: android, slider, translation

I am a newbie of Android development. I want to implement a sliding button with animation. The effect is shown in the following video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ImHe4N4mvE4. This is like "slide to unlock" effect of iphone. My question is that how to impelment this kind of effect. Is this app implemented with changeview, scrollview ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can put an image view with animation in a linear layout whose height is wrap content and width is fill parent

code for animation

```
    public static Animation inFromLeftAnimation() {
 Animation inFromLeft = new TranslateAnimation(
 Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  -1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f,
 Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,   0.0f
 );
 inFromLeft.setDuration(350);
 inFromLeft.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
 return inFromLeft;
 }
public static Animation outToLeftAnimation() {
Animation outtoLeft = new TranslateAnimation(
 Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  -1.0f,
 Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,   0.0f
);
outtoLeft.setDuration(350);
outtoLeft.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
return outtoLeft;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I want to move the slider with finger speed. in This code speed is fixed.

Comment: change the animation accordingly as per your wish

Comment: or just customise the sliding drawer ( set drawers caller to invisible

Comment: Thank you very much.This is not awesome,But i can implement it temporary.Thanks again.

Comment: yap just try improving it if you get a better way don't forget to post thanks

Comment: I move handle in sliding drawer and when it reaches more 50% height of the screen it go automatically to the last positions.my question is how to increase this range,so when I my finger reaches to end of the screen it drawer slides in????

Comment: you should probably customize the drawer to accomplish that there are a lot of coustamised verssions available

Comment: or you can actually customize the animation given above as per your need